# Rejecting oraclize scheduled request

Tags: solidity, oracles, scheduling

Using Oracle we can call scheduled functions. But is it possible to cancel scheduled function? I mean, for example, if I scheduled an function that updates something in my contract in 10 minutes but in 5 minutes I changed my mind, I don't need update something. In this case, can I cancel scheduled function?

Comment: A small piece of advice: if you're hoping to get a proper answer - more code, less words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Oraclize does not allow you to cancel your request. Other options allow this, for instance [Aion Scheduling System](https://aion.ethpantheon.com) allows you to cancel the request and get back the fee if you cancel at least 20 blocks before the scheduled time. Ethereum clock Alarm also allows you to cancel scheduled transactions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to save an id when the call is scheduled and revert when the oracle call and you do not want to process that id.

But since the call was done the system may charge for it anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to revert but with standard payment model of Oraclize, you pre-pay for callbacks so it's counter-productive. Anyway, thanks for your answer!